# PHP Static Array Workaround

Tags: php, arrays, class, static

I have an array structure with key and value pairs that are multiple dimensions deep.  I want to use this array in a class, but I don't want it added to each instance, since it is simply a reference needed by that class.

This is the workaround I have come up with through Google and Stack Overflow searching.  It works for what I need, but are there any obvious issues more experienced PHP programmers can see with it?

```
class Foo {

    public static function bar($key = null) {

        $array = array('key'=>array(1,2,3));

        if ($key && array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return $array[$key];
        } else {
            return $array;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with using a `static` class variable? What problem is your workaround solving?

Comment: Actually, what is your intent to begin with? It is unclear what you're trying to do and hence impossible to answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

static variables are NOT meant for this purpose. If you want to have a per-instance value, just use it in an OOP context:

```
class Foo {

    protected $myArray = array();

    public function __construct($array = array())
    {
        $this->myArray = $array;
    }

}

$array1 = array('key' => array(1,2,3));
$array2 = array('key' => array(4,5,6));

$foo1 = new Foo($array1);
$foo2 = new Foo($array2);
```

Comment: He said he *didn't* want per instance values.

Comment: No, he said he didn't want that value added to each instance. To me that means that it IS a per-instance value.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. You're correct, this is the best and proper way to do it. Static methods used in this manner are pointless you may as well use $_GLOBALS as it will serve an identical purpose and cause identical problems.

Comment: OK, I see that the OP's question is vague enough to be meaningless, and this answer is not necessarily wrong. Depends on how you understand the question. Removing downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare static variables in the class and then access them using `self`.

```
class Foo {
  public static $bar = array(...);
  function Foo()
  {
    print_r(self::$bar)
  }
}   
print_r(Foo::$bar);
```

You can also check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: I like this, but it requires the use of an init function, which I would prefer to avoid (so that the array can be accessed even before the class is initiated).

Comment: @RedBassett, then you can assign it in the variable declaration statement. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass your array by reference to each instance. This is done by using the `&` before the variable name like this:

```
&$SomeArray;
```

Comment: And this has to do what exactly with `static` class variables?

Comment: Nothing but his problem does neither. He doesn't want to pass an array as value to all instances of a class. Using a static variable is one way to do it, but passing the array as reference also works.

Comment: And the advantage of passing by reference as opposed to by value is...?

Comment: You only have 1 instance of the array. So if you have 100 objects with the same array you will still have only 1 array, instead of 100. If you pass by value, the array will be copied every time it is passed, so you will end up with 100 arrays if you have 100 objects.

Comment: Nope. PHP uses copy-on-write. A copy is only created if you *alter* the array, not if you just pass it around. Passing by reference is a logical operation, not a memory-optimization operation. Only pass by reference if you mean to pass by reference because you need to alter the original.

Comment: See http://3v4l.org/IgUiK.

Comment: I was not aware of the fact the php use copy-on-write, which makes my point invalid. ;)